# OpenGL: glGenBuffer vs glGenBuffersARB

Tags: c++, opengl

What is the difference between the functions `glGenBuffers()`/`glBufferData()`/etc, and the functions with ARB appended to the function name `glGenBuffersARB()`/`glBufferDataARB()`/etc.  I tried searching around but no one ever points out the difference, merely they just use one or the other.

Also, is it common for either function to be unavailable on some computers?  What's the most common way of getting around that kind of situation without falling back to immediate mode?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`glGenBuffers()` is a core OpenGL function in OpenGL 1.5 and later; `glGenBuffersARB()` was an extension implementing the same functionality in earlier versions.

Unless you're developing for an ancient system, there's no longer any reason to use the ARB extension.

Comment: glGetString(GL_VERSION) can get the version of OGL supported. You should not worry about 1.5 and 2.0 compatibility - the newer versions of OpenGL, 3.0 and 4.0, cause much bigger issues.